# beforeRouteEnter does not set value on 2nd visit

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Short explanation:

- first load = ok
- press back, then press forward (or go to other route and get back to the previous)
- second load = no data

Long explanation:

I have a very simple code inside beforeRouteEnter. I just fetch using axios, use `then`, execute `next(vm => .....)` inside.

First load, data are being set. e.g `vm.someData = 'value'`
Second time that route is visited, `someData` is empty. Not set.

**EDIT**

Tried to remove axios to see if it's really the `router`. Here's the code

`beforeRouteEnter (...) {
 next(vm => vm.someData = 'data')
}`

`someData` is still empty on second visit

**EDIT**

Saw the bottom part of https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/data-fetching.html

I followed the `watch` part but it doesn't even react at all.

**EDIT**

Seems like a bug: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1322

Comment: What if you use beforeRouteUpdate?

Comment: beforeRouteUpdate is not for my use case. See the git issue. It looks like it is a legit bug. It has a fiddle there you can try.